# NuGet resolves the wrong version of package dependency

Tags: .net, nuget

So I have a package, NServiceBus.Host that depends on NServiceBus >= 4.5.0.

On nuget there is a 4.5.1 version of NServiceBus. When I install-package NServiceBus.Host I get:

```
PM> install-package nservicebus.host
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NServiceBus (≥ 4.5.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NServiceBus.Interfaces (≥ 4.5.0)'.
Installing 'NServiceBus.Interfaces 4.5.0'.
You are downloading NServiceBus.Interfaces from NServiceBus Ltd, the license agreement to which is available at http://particular.net/LicenseAgreement. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'NServiceBus.Interfaces 4.5.0'.
Installing 'NServiceBus 4.5.0'.
```

As you can see I get the 4.5.0 version of the dependency.

In the [nuget doco](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dependency%20Resolution) it states:

> If the dependency is not installed, NuGet goes through the following
>   steps:
>
> NuGet enumerates every version of Subkismet within the feed that’s
>   within the version specification. NuGet then narrows that set to just
>   the packages with the lowest Major/Minor version. Of the remaining
>   packages, NuGet picks the one with the highest version number.

"NuGet picks the one with the highest version number." seems to be violated here since there is a never version.

Is this a bug in NuGet?

Comment: You missed a bit when you requoted part of the documentation if your penultimate paragraph: "*Of the remaining packages*, NuGet picks the one with the highest version number" - There may be a higher version number on in the NuGet repository, but that is not the highest number referenced by your package or its dependencies.

Comment: But in this case both 4.5.0 and 4.5.1 should be included in that set of remaining packages right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The NuGet documentation on dependency resolution you refer to hasn't been updated since Dec 2010. The real NuGet docs are available here: https://docs.nuget.org

Also, NuGet will - by default - resolve the lowest major.minor version within the range allowed, as defined in the package dependencies. So 4.5.0 is a correct default dependency resolution.

New since NuGet v2.8.1: you can use an alternate dependency resolution algorithm using the NuGet Package Manager Console:

> Install-Package NServiceBus.Host -DependencyVersion HighestPatch

There are more options, check the docs here:
https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Install-Package

Comment: Thanks, can we expect the HighestPatch to become the default strategy in the future?

Comment: Can you only specify this with Powershell? I dont see the option on the regular command prompt.

Comment: Is there a similar strategy to force HighestMinor?  I mean according to semver they are compatible so why should anyone want the oldest version?

Comment: Doh, I need to learn to read! Its there in the doco,   - HighestMinor: the version with the lowest major, highest minor, highest patch;

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund If only all package authors would properly use SemVer, then it could be a good default. But SemVer isn't idiot-proof and is just a way of "stating intentions", it's not exact science. Hence NuGet better stays on the safe side for now and allows consumers to decide :)

Answer (score 6):

As Xavier mentioned this seems default behaviour. However, the documentation says you can change default behavior by editing nuget configuration:

> Specifies the version of the dependency package to be selected from the list of valid        dependency packages. The defult value is Lowest. You can override this default value by specifying a new default value in nuget.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="DependencyVersion" value="HighestPatch" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

I edited my configuration file as described in the documentation:

```
%AppData%\Nuget\NuGet.Config
```

It then works in Powershell but NOT in a regular command prompt.

The docs also says:

What is strange is that the docs says that pre 2.7.2 the default was HighestPatch...

> Note that for NuGet 2.7.2 or earlier, the default value is HighestPatch, and it cannot be changed.

The release notes of 2.8 mention the change in behavior and for the reason that install package now has a consistent dependency resolution result over time.

https://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.8