# NServiceBus nuget package installing 3.5?

Tags: nservicebus, nuget-package

I am very confused about Nuget and NServiceBus (mainly NServiceBus). I am using the command:

```
install-package NServiceBus
```

This installs version 3.5.0.0? Which I found very strange as I imagine it is suppose to be picking up the latest version? So I tried this command:

```
install-package NServiceBus -version 4.5.0.0
```

This presents me the error of unable to resolve dependency NServiceBus (> 4.5.0)

Any ideas what I need to do to get this installed and why its redirecting and installing an older version?

Cheers, DS.

Comment: What is the version of visual studio you are using and also what is the .net version of your project set to?

Comment: Using VS 2013 and created a console app based on .net 4.5

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384514/nuget-resolves-the-wrong-version-of-package-dependency

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it and i get

```
PM> Install-Package NServiceBus
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NServiceBus.Interfaces (≥ 4.6.1)'.
Installing 'NServiceBus.Interfaces 4.6.1'.
You are downloading NServiceBus.Interfaces from NServiceBus Ltd, the license agreement to which is available at http://particular.net/LicenseAgreement. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'NServiceBus.Interfaces 4.6.1'.
Installing 'NServiceBus 4.6.1'.
You are downloading NServiceBus from NServiceBus Ltd, the license agreement to which is available at http://particular.net/LicenseAgreement. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'NServiceBus 4.6.1'.

Type 'get-help about_NServiceBus' to see all available NServiceBus commands.

Adding 'NServiceBus.Interfaces 4.6.1' to ClassLibrary1.
Successfully added 'NServiceBus.Interfaces 4.6.1' to ClassLibrary1.
Adding 'NServiceBus 4.6.1' to ClassLibrary1.
Successfully added 'NServiceBus 4.6.1' to ClassLibrary1.
```